# getting webservice's ApplicationPool

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I have some web service running on my computer how can I get by webservice name it's application pool settings ?

I just need to change programmatic way  it's "Enable 32 bit Applications" flag.

I am talking about IIS7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly in order to get all sorts of information about your IIS setup.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx) is a link to an article about it.  In your case it would look something like this:

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
manager.ApplicationPools[
    manager.Sites["yoursite"].Applications["servicePath"].ApplicationPoolName].
    Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;
```

That ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`Microsoft.Web.Administration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.aspx) namespace - the [`ServerManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager_members.aspx) class is a good starting point, giving you access to all websites, application pools etc.